# Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/ and try installing again

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to use webpack + react + electron, and when I type in the CLI "electron ."  it gives me this error:

[image]

I deleted node_modules and re-installed all the modules over and over like about 6 times, obviously deleting node_modules and installing isn't a solution, so I need the community's help on finding this error.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ElectronULTIMA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron apps",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "electron": "^1.6.1",
    "electron-packager": "^8.5.2",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "electron": "^1.6.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-modal": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, dialog, Menu, Tray, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ep = new AWS.Endpoint('dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({      // Dynamo database constructor
    "apiVersion": '2012-08-10',
    "region": 'us-west-1',
    "endpoint": ep,
    "accessKeyId": '*censored*',
    "secretAccessKey": '*censored*'
});


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//  RENDER COMMUNICATION
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
let win; // Main project window
let rnews; // Rnews window

    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 700 });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    //win.openDevTools();




    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // RNEWS WINDOW INSTANCE
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    rnews = new BrowserWindow({ width: 620, height: 900, show: false, backgroundColor: '#2e2c29', title: '"R" News Articles' });
    // useContentSize (boolean)
    // RNEWS WINDOW VISIBILITY
    ipc.on('rnews', () => {
        rnews.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/rnews/index.html`);
        //rnews.openDevTools();
        if (rnews.isVisible()) { rnews.hide(); }
        if (!rnews.isVisible()) { rnews.show(); }
    });



    win.on('closed', () => { win = null; });
    rnews.on('closed', () => { rnews = null; });
    rnews.on('ready-to-show', () => {
      rnews.show();
    });
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//  GLOBAL SCOPE
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
app.on('ready', MAIN_WINDOW);
// When the last window is closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});
app.on ('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        MAIN_WINDOW();
    }
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
      './index.js'
    ],
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: './bundle.js' },
    resolve: { modules: ['node_modules', 'src'], extensions: ['.js'] },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    target: "node",
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { InputGroup, Button, ButtonToolbar, ButtonGroup, FormControl, FormGroup, render } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ep = new AWS.Endpoint('dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({      // Dynamo database constructor
    "apiVersion": '2012-08-10',
    "region": 'us-west-1',
    "endpoint": ep,
    "accessKeyId": '*censored*',
    "secretAccessKey": '*censored*'
});


const GRAB_RNEWS_ARTICLES = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.scan({ TableName: 'Rnews' }, (error, articles) => {
    if (error) reject (error);
    resolve(articles);
  });
});

function RenderImage(props) {
  // If thumbnailOrNo is passed as a prop give it the class "rnewsThumbnails"
  if (props.thumbnailOrNo) {
    return (
      <img src={props.imageUrl} className="img-rounded rnewsThumbnails"></img>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <img src={props.imageUrl} className="img-rounded"></img>
    )
  }
}





RNEWS();
function RNEWS() {
  GRAB_RNEWS_ARTICLES.then(rArticles => {

    $(function() {
      // Make all links open in new tab
      $("a").attr('target', '_blank');
    });

    class RNEWS_Templating extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // don't forget this.props.article is passed as an individual article
      }
      render() {
        let defaultImg = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Lk5XNJRyFKw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAA0/xkk9_owpEhE/photo.jpg';
        return (
          <div className="panel panel-warning">
            <div className="panel-body">
              <div className="col-sm-2">
                <strong className="articlesource">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.props.article.source}</strong>
                <br />
                <RenderImage imageUrl={this.props.article.imgUrl || defaultImg } thumbnailOrNo="yes" />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-10">
                  <strong>Short title: </strong><span className="rnewsshorttitle"><font size="4">{this.props.article.title}</font></span>
                  <br />
                  <span className="rnewsdescription">{this.props.article.description}</span>
                  <br />
                <a href={this.props.article.url}>{this.props.article.url}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // RNEWS_Parent will hold the states
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    class RNEWS_Parent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          articles: this.props.rArticles.Items,
          searchVal: "",
          titles: []
        }
        this.searchValueUpdater = this.searchValueUpdater.bind(this);
      }
      searchValueUpdater(e) {
        this.setState({ searchVal: e.target.value })
      }
      componentWillMount() {
        this.state.articles.map(article => {
          return this.state.titles.push(article.title);
        })
      }
      render() {
        // Will be used to show only 10 articles
        let TwentyArticles = 0;
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="well row">
              <center>
                <font size="5">"R" News Articles (ascending order)</font>
              </center>
              <div>
                <h6>Total articles: <span className="goldenvalue">{this.props.rArticles.Count}</span></h6>
                <h6>Total scanned articles: <span className="goldenvalue">{this.props.rArticles.ScannedCount}</span></h6>
              </div>
              <FormGroup bsSize="sm" controlId="rnewsSearch" validationState="success">
                <FormControl
                  placeholder="Search for an article"
                  inputRef={(input) => { this.input = input; }}
                  onChange={this.searchValueUpdater}
                  >
                </FormControl>
              </FormGroup>
              <span>{this.state.searchVal}</span>
              <div>
                <h3><font color="magenta">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Articles: </font></h3>
                <br /><br />
                <div className="col-sm-8">
                    {this.state.articles.map((articleObj, key) => {
                      TwentyArticles++;
                      if (TwentyArticles > 20) { return; }
                      return <RNEWS_Templating article={articleObj} />
                    })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }


    ReactDOM.render(<RNEWS_Parent rArticles={rArticles}/>, document.getElementById("ace"));
  });
}
```

Comment: Try changing `target: "node"` to `target: "electron"` in webpack.config.js

Comment: This comment should be promoted to the answer.

Comment: target: 'electron-renderer', works for me

Answer (score 24):

I had to go to `node_modules/electron` and run `node install.js` manually.

Comment: Super frustrating, having followed the Electron Quick Start, then chased this error around for well over an hour.  Finally got it working with this tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens due to bad network so the dependencies aren't downloaded and installed correctly.

Make sure to delete `node_modules` folder and run `yarn cache clean` or `npm cache verify` to make sure the cache is healed from corruption issues.

Now install your dependencies again `npm install` or `yarn` and everything should work properly.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I tried to bundle my `main.js` but **including** electron. The solution was to mark "electron" as **external** module (not including it into the build output), and then everything worked again.

Comment: it's my case, but adding to externals only changed the error message to 'electron is not defined'

Comment: and what worked: `externals: { electron: 'require("electron")' }`...  ️ don't judge me

Answer (score 4):

This is voodoo, but it worked for me:

```
rm -r node_modules/electron
npm install
npm start      # Oh no! Still broken!

rm package-lock.json
npm install
npm start      # Darn it! Same error as ever!

rm -r node_modules/electron  # One more time, for good luck
npm install
npm start        # Yayy! It worked!
```

So I guess that (for me) both electron, and `package-lock.json` had to be removed.

Comment: yes @Linas, it worked for me after removing both node_modules and package-lock.json file. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 2):

Solved on raspberry Pi4 with:

```sh
npm i -D electron --arch=armv7l
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the issue but you are including `Electron` twice:

```
  "electron": "^1.6.1",
  "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
```

> [Installation](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt)
>   Note As of version 1.3.1, this package is published to npm under two
>   names: electron and electron-prebuilt. You can currently use either
>   name, but electron is recommended, as the electron-prebuilt name is
>   deprecated, and will only be published until the end of 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory node_modules/ and delete electron directory.

After that run  `npm install electron --save-dev`. it will solve ur problem.

Comment: After installing electron-builder I was able to succesfully create exe file, but then started getting this error when I went back to do more development on original code. Doing this answer fixed it so it works correctly for both `npm start` and `npm run dist`

Comment: which node_modules directory? I don't see one

Answer (score 1):

Solved this exact issue by understanding that I had both local and global installation of electron with different versions, npm install -g electron@wantedVersion fixed the issue, I guess uninstalling the global one would have solved it as well

Answer (score 0):

The question was also asked [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8466) and [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20994).

But the explanation and a workaround was described [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20731#issuecomment-553796146):

Download of the electron package by install.js fails silently,
one should download manualy the zip of the package.

I wasn't successful using browsers, but it worked using curl :

> curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL curl 7.55.1 (Windows)
>   libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL Release-Date: [unreleased] Protocols: dict file
>   ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL

and the following command:

```
curl -L -O https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v7.1.9/electron-v7.1.9-win32-x64.zip
```

- Download the zip archive in your project,
- Then edit the installation script under .\node_modules\electron\install.js
  for it to use the archive instead of any download attempt:

Replace the downloadArtifact bloc:

```
// downloads if not cached
//downloadArtifact({
// ...
//})
```

.. by this unziping command:

```
extractFile('./electron-v7.1.9-win32-x64.zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case
after run this cmd **`sudo npm install`**

please wait for some time to install **`electron`**

will show something like following this in my case after hit **`sudo npm install`**

```
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [==========---------------------------------------------------------------] 14% ETA: 445.2 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [==========---------------------------------------------------------------] 14% ETA: 461.5 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 426.5 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 427.6 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 428.6 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 429.8 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 430.5 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 431.9 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 432.5 seconds 
Downloading electron-v8.5.5-linux-x64.zip: [===========--------------------------------------------------------------] 15% ETA: 433.8 seconds
```

Then Run **`npm run electron`**

May be will work
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me for a different reason than anyone has mentioned here. I'll leave this answer just in case anyone is in this situation.

I was switching an electron app to use `contextIsolation` for better security. So I created a `preload.js` and used `electron.contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld`. However, after doing this, I kept getting the error mentioned in this question. As it turns out, I just forgot to update my `BrowserWindow` settings:

```js
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 800,
        width: 672,
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        frame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: false, // <----- SHOULD BE TRUE
            nodeIntegration: true // <------ SHOULD BE FALSE
        },
    })
```

Posting this because this is the first result in google for this error and there is no indication as to what's causing it. Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use bunch of answers, neither but only one worked which was provided by @www as comment to question:

In webpack configuration set:
`target: "electron"`

Note: in current webpack version there are multiple targets for electron (`electron-main`, `electron-preload`, `electron-renderer`), choose one of those for corresponding parts of application

Answer (score -2):

See in the message that it is saying that there is a directory where the global npm package is installed. In your case it is inside:
**node_modules/**

So go to that directory and delete all the directory named prefixing electron.

Now run 
**npm install -g react-devtools**

After that you are ready to roll.

To start the dev tools, write the following command.

**react-devtools**