# Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again

Tags: node.js, electron

It seems strange to me one thing, during the installation of modules, apparently does not finish correctly, because it remains as follows:

```
npm install electron
electron@1.4.15 postinstall D:\Yididiya Master\Development\Electron\simple-samples-master\activity-monitor\node_modules\electron
node install.js
```

(It remains on hold)

Comment: I have also experienced the same problem in past. My solution was to wait for long time, due to my low internet speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in the message that it is saying that there is a directory where the global npm package is installed. In your case it is inside:
**D:\Yididiya Master\Development\Electron\simple-samples-master\activity-monitor\node_modules**

Now try to install that again.

Comment: what to do with that directory?

Comment: in my case, réinstalling did not worked, I had to use the following workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777868/1767316