# Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again. Could it be a conflict of versions?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have installed electron and tried to run the simples hello world application but got this error

> throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete
>   node_modules/electron and try installing again')

I already did the usual things suggested in questions like this here (so please don't mark this as "duplicate question": those answer *don't work*) I deleted node_modules and the problem is still there.

Investigating furthermore I discovered that the problem is in line 7 of file index.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt')

function getElectronPath () {
  if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {   //<=====HERE!!!!!
    var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8')
    if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
      return path.join(process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH, executablePath)
    }
    return path.join(__dirname, 'dist', executablePath)
  } else {
    throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again')
  }
}

module.exports = getElectronPath()
```

and yes, the file "path.txt" does not exist in the installation.

Is it possible by anychance that this is a problem of versions? I have had installed nodejs for quite a time and I just installed electron.

```
npm -v
5.5.1
node -v
v8.9.1
npm list --depth=0 -g
+-- electron@7.1.1
```

I just realize that I cannot even execute `electron -v'. If this is the problem how can I uninstall node and electron to start over?

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following steps in order to solve the problem:

- Create a file named path.txt in node_modules\electron folder.
- Write `electron.exe` in it.
- Download electron package manualy. Maybe from: https://fossies.org/windows/www/electron-v7.1.7-win32-x64.zip/
- Unpackage the electron files into node_modules\electron\dist
- Run your start script

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you run this command after deleting the node_modules directory:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be a download problem of the package from the js installation script failing silently. 
If you encouter this problem, reinstalling electron will be of no help.
rather use this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777868/1767316), it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Environment:

```
macOS version 10.15.5
Electron v9.1.2
```

Sometimes there is somethings wrong with the network of downloading of Electron.You must delete the `node_modules/electron` directory and then run the following command:

```
ELECTRON_MIRROR="https://cdn.npm.taobao.org/dist/electron/" npm install electron
```

You can modify the `ELECTRON_MIRROR` where you can access it.